# Feeding data into database with Php form and using that data into JSON format to be used in D3

Tags: javascript, php, json, d3.js

All I want to do is to get some data from JSON file for my D3.js in real time that too from user directly and get updated instantly.

There will be a **php form** from which data will be stored into database and the data from the database will be converted into JSON file which will be used by d3.js for some visualization technique.

**Problem I am facing**

I am not sure whether I can get the data from **php form** and convert it to JSON file instantly and can use for my Visualization model. I can convert the data into into database into JSON file but not sure how to do it one go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you want a json file if your data is saved on database? Just json_encode($array_of_your_data_from_database) will give you a json respond easily.

Comment: It means there is no need to convert that data in database into JSON file separately but to use it directly from database with above function ?

Comment: Definitely...Query your database how you want and return as json_encode($data)